# Adding image to CALayer/CAShapeLayer always shows black color

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add an image inside a circular `CAShapeLayer` so i started by creating a circle like so :

```
let circleContainer = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: pCenter, radius: radius - 10, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI * 2), clockwise: true)
let imageSubLayer = CAShapeLayer()
imageSubLayer.path = circleContainer.CGPath

self.view.layer.addSublayer(imageSubLayer)
```

then to add the image i did:

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "pic")?.CGImage
imageSubLayer.addSublayer(imageLayer)

//I've also tried adding the image directly to the circular CAShapeLayer like so but without any success:
imageSubLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "pic")?.CGImage
```

the problem is: the `circleContainer` is always showing black color when i run the app (see image below). what am i doing wrong ?
thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not set the frame of `imageLayer`. But it's also not clear what exactly you're trying to achieve. If you want your image to mask to your shape layer you'll need to set it to the mask property of `imageLayer`:

```
let imageLayer = CALayer()
imageLayer.contents = UIImage(named: "pic")?.CGImage
imageLayer.frame = view.bounds
imageLayer.mask = imageSubLayer
view.layer.addSublayer(imageLayer)
```

#### Update

If you have this code in `drawRect` you can draw directly into the `CGContext` of the view. For example:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
{
    super.drawRect(rect)
    let circleRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, 10, 10)
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: circleRect)
    path.lineWidth = 10
    UIColor.yellowColor().set()
    path.stroke()
    path.fill()
    path.addClip()
    let image = UIImage(named: "pic")
    image?.drawInRect(circleRect)
}
```

The above code draws a yellow circle with an image in the center clipped to the bounds of the circle.

Comment: i simply want to add an image on top of a circular shapeLayer! its like a play/pause button! ive tried setting the frame of the imageLayer but the problem persist! ive also tried setting the fillColor of the imageLayer to UIColor with pattern and tadda the image showed up but it like many images next to each other maybe i should play with the fillMode or fillRule to make it appear as one image

Comment: Seems like something that's more appropriate for a `UIButton` that has corner radius set and masks to bounds. Did you try the code I posted? Notice I'm adding the layer to the view's layer and not the shape layer.

Comment: Yes i did! please keep in mind that im doing the hole drawing thing in override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)!

Comment: Why not draw directly into the the `CGContext` then? Adding sublayers in `drawRect` is not recommended, as `drawRect` can be called repeatedly over the lifetime of a view, which could cause poor performance.

Comment: thanks, i didnt know about the performance thing! and your code is working like charm!